# Realm migration crash upgrading from multiple version

Tags: realm, swift4

```
func runMigration(migration: Migration, olderVersion: UInt64, newVersion: UInt64) {
    // upgrade from version 2 to 3
        if olderVersion <= 2 && newVersion >= 3 {
            update2to3(migration)
        }

    // upgrade from version 3 to 4
        if olderVersion <= 3 && newVersion >= 4 {
            update3to4(migration)
        }
}

private func update2to3(_ migration: Migration) {
    migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: Student.className(), {oldObject, newObject in
            newObject?[“address”] = “”
        })
}

private func update3to4(_ migration: Migration) {
    migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: Student.className(), {oldObject, newObject in
            newObject?[“address”] = oldObject?["address"] ?? nil
        })
}
```

Example the current realm schema version is 2 and the user upgrading to latest build version 4 (skipping the version 3). The above will execute the `update2to3()` this method will add the `address` property which is added in the version 3. Then will execute the `update3to4()` which migrate the `address` property to *optional/nullable* property.

Can anybody tell me what's wrong with the above code? Why when the `update3to4()` executed it crashes because the `address` property doesn't exists? How come the  `address` property doesn't exist when on `update2to3()` will create this property?

This is the crash error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Invalid property name 'address' for class 'Student'.'
```

NOTE:
This only happen when the user upgrades from 2 to 4, but if the user upgrades from 2, 3 then 4 this error won't occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`update2to3` does not create `address` on `oldObject` (and it is not possible to do that). When upgrading directly from version 2 to 4, both `update2to3` and `update3to4` get version 2 `oldObject`s and version 4 `newObject`s.

For the migrations shown in your question, the simplest fix is to just delete the migration functions entirely, as they're just repeating what Realm does automatically when new properties are added.

Comment: that's what I notice to. The oldObject doesn't have yet the "address" field. We can't remove the migration because Realm crashes when new property is added. That's is why we create the migration when we add the "address" field because Realm complains that the property isn't exist in the previous version.

Comment: You have to bump the schema version when adding a property, but the migration function doesn't need to do anything.

Comment: Do you mean I just have to increment the schema version and that would the tricks? I'm confuse because most threads I found telling me to increment the schema version and create the migration block. Anyway, we just removed the changes in `update3to4` but the `update2to3` still there because the app has been deployed for production use.

BTW, I accepted this answer because it explain the reason why it's happening.

Comment: Yes, unless you specifically want to initialize the new property to something other than the "empty" value for that type, all you have to do when adding a new property is increment the schema version.